# Temporary Tables and SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, replication

I'm a bit of a noob, so pardon me if the answer to this question seems obvious. I have been tasked with the creation of SSIS packages that will operate in an environment maintained by another company. They're using replication to publish updates from client sites to a centralized server, and I'm not entirely certain how they've got it set up.

Generally speaking, are there any considerations to keep in mind when creating and then dropping global temporary tables from within a stored procedure or SSIS package on a SQL Server 2005 instance that is part of a transactional replication setup? Or are temporary tables always local to the client DB instance? I want to be *very* sure that I don't create a concurrency problem.

Comment: Why use a global temp table anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temp tables are created in the tempdb.
The tempdb would not be replicated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx

> > Or are temporary tables always local to the client DB instance?

"available to all users connected to the instance of SQL Server"